# Responsive header image (Bootstrap 3/4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After posting before I'm running into more problems with making my header responsive. I want to make my header image (logo) re-size down correctly with the browser and look correct on mobile devices.

like this web page does when re-sized down: http://timeandspace.org/

here is the fiddle link: www.jsfiddle.net/0m4z6u25/

Any tips on how to get the nav bar to do the same as the website linked up above will be a huge help!

Thanks

Comment: you can use [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to hide/show certain elements when screen size is small

Comment: Thank you that helps, but still my logo isn't responsive and its resizing down too small. I need it to do is keep its size and keep its place while re-sizing down and viewing on mobile devices.

Comment: Your image gets smaller on small screen sizes because you added `max-width:100%` in your style. If you don't want it to change size, then you can have fixed width and height [ex](http://jsfiddle.net/j24mq1jc/)

Comment: I think you should edit your question to describe the behavior you want to achieve in more details. The link you provided may become unavailable after some time, thus making your question unclear.

Comment: @firegurafiku will do! Thanks

Comment: @RainMan This worked perfectly...looks exactly how I want it to across mobile devices! Thanks man

Comment: Not related to your question, but your home page is slow to load (3 to 5 seconds) when I tested it, I know you might not care, but just in case!

Comment: @JeffArries the one I linked? or in jfiddle? May be the fonts it's loading.

Comment: Your website www.spaceandtime.org, but I tried it again and it wasn't as slow, maybe it was just that one time, doesn't really matter. Anyway great Domain Name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly update the version of the bootstrap.css, use the latest stable to date(v3.3.6).

CDN link

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Next, You need to make lot of changes to your navbar code. I have made the changes to resemble your requirements. Here

```
<!--HEADER-->                      
<div class="header">
  <div id="header-container" class="container">
    <div class="headerdiv">
      <a href="" class="headerleft">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DotvQDw.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="header SU">
      </a>
    </div>     
  </div>
</div> 

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="nav-main">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img alt="Brand" width="20" height="20" src="img/nav_logo.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

and the CSS is

```
/* Stylesheet */

html, 
body {

height:100%;    
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}


/* Salford SU Header */

.headerbox {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:white;
}


#header-container{
    padding-left: 140px;
    padding-right: 140px;
}



.headerdiv {
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 65px;
    padding-right: 65px;
}

.headerleft {
    height: 146px;
    min-width:400px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-position: center left;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

.header-right {
    width: 40%;
    height: 146px;
    float: right;
    border-left: 2px solid #c5c6c8;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.headerright1 
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-top: 7px;
}

.headerright1 > a {
    width: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    zoom: 1;
}


/*
#cover {
    background:#222 url('img/header.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    color:white;
    height: 24.5%;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    align-items:bottom;
}
*/


 /*NAVIGATION CSS*/
#nav-main {
    background: #ed1e24;
}

#nav-main li {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:white;
}

.section-content {
    padding: 5rem 0;
}

#about {
    background: url('img/working.jpg') center center no-repeat;
}

.about-text{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: white;
    padding: 1.875rem;
}

#footer-main {
    background: #f1163e;
    color:white;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}



@media (min-width: 158px) and (max-width: 600px) {
#header-container {
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
}

    .headerleft {
        background-position: center left;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .headerleft > a {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        background-position: center left;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m4z6u25/7/)

Comment: Would you be able to write any of the CSS out or tweak mine a little? Literally started coding 2 weeks a go and what I'm trying isn't working with the CSS. Would be a massive help.

Comment: I could bang my head on a wall, for the life of me I can't get the CSS to style it. Even copying and pasting your code breaks it on my local browser.

Comment: The HTML is updated too. I added the `id` attribute here. `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="nav-main">`. May be that's why your styles are not getting applied.

Answer (score 1):

Using media queries, you will need to resize the header image based on the screen width. You can then control the size, keeping it in proportion, and then you can show a different layout logo when on mobile - for example putting 'student's union' under the circle. This will not make it too small, and look good on a mobile.

An example of a media query:

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {}
```

Bootstrap also has some responsive classes such as `visible-xs` `hidden-xs` which could help here.